# How to customise a Laravel application

Tags: laravel

I'm total newbie with Laravel, so the question might not be the most intelligent, be gentle, please.

I'd like to use an Open Source application made with Laravel. However, the application does not fully suit my needs, hence some customization is needed.

Naturally, I don't what to change the application files and also want to keep all my files separated.

In other PHP-based  applications there are typically methods to customise the app without touching any other code. Also, it is possible to have own code nicely in one place. For instance, Wordpress has a theme concept, child theme concept, plugins and hooks in code (filters and actions). In Magento we have a simple method of overriding a core file by copying it to local code pool, as well as a more sophisticated dependency injection, which allows to override any class anywhere.

I've been trying to understand what is the correct way to customise a Laravel application in such a way, that my own modifications are separated from the base application and e.g. updating the base is possible.

Please guide me, or give pointers on how to do this.

Comment: It all depends on what the application is you want to use. If it is a package, most of the time there are ways to implement these the way you like. If it is a full Laravel application, you will probably have to edit the existing code to your likings.

Comment: Thanks @Jerodev, would be great if you can elaborate and make it an answer

Comment: Laravel is a framework. WordPress/Magento are *applications*. A specific app built *with* Laravel may have WP/Magento-style hooks and plugin systems, but Laravel itself doesn't inherently require such a thing be in place.

Comment: @ceejayoz, understand, but I see e.g. depency injection more like a framework type of thing, rather than something that belongs to the application level.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Packages might be your best option.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/packages

They let you customize very much in your application without touching other parts of the code, as well as keeping it separated from the other parts of the application.

Here's a getting started guide on packages:

https://medium.com/@lasselehtinen/getting-started-on-laravel-package-development-a62110c58ba1

Comment: This will only help if the existing open source application being used already has support for packages built-in. Otherwise, at least *some* code changes will need to be made.